# Optimize regexp for HTML parsing

Tags: java, regex, performance

I use this regex:

```
.*[hH]([1-9])\\.\\s*(.*)\\s*
```

using java with `Matcher.find()` method.

On long text this regex take a lot of time to find results.

How I can optimize the regex? Someone can propose to me some optimized regexp?

Comment: can you give example of what you are trying to match?

Comment: If you're using Matcher.find then why do you need the leading `.*`?

Comment: Here an example: H1. Lorem ipsum

H2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
Nullam non augue ornare, vehicula nulla ac, tempor mi. Praesent accumsan consectetur tortor, in sodales odio fringilla quis. Suspendisse volutpat nunc id varius fringilla. Quisque id tortor non...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
[hH]([1-9])\\.\\s*+(\\S+)
```

where `\\S` is all that is not a white character (the negation of `\\s`)

[Possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) `*+` is used to forbid backtracking.

As Ian Roberts noticed it in his comment, the leading `(.*)` seems useless here.

Answer (score 0):

You should test the long text *before* trying to run regex against it.

```
String longText=...
if(longText.matches(myRegex)) {
    //Matcher.find
}
```

This way you won't waste your time.

However, if you really face longt text, may I suggest you to use the **powerful html parser** [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) ?